# Cleanly uninstall ubuntu from Nexus 7

Tags: bootloader, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

If I install Ubuntu on the Nexus 7 (following the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation), and later uninstall it, will the device be in the original state, or will there be traces left behind?

I'm especially concerned about the following:

- Do I void the warranty? (In practice, not strictly legally. Can I bring the re-flashed device back to the store and pretend it's original?)
- Can I re-lock the bootloader?
- Are there 'fuses' or tamper detection switches that tell that there was once something else installed?
- Do I loose features in Android if I once unlocked the bootloader or installed Ubuntu (like being able to play DRMed videos)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Installing Ubuntu on Nexus7 *does not* require rooting the phone.  It does require unlocking the boot loader which will void your warranty as stated on the device when you unlock it.  You can re-lock it later, but unfortunately I don't know if there are any counters that that will be able to use to detect you've tampered with it.

EDIT: chris-wayne who is on my team at Canonical called Google and they stated on the phone that unlocking your bootloader, installing something, then reflashing back to stock and re-locking will NOT void your warranty. We unfortunately don't have this in writing, but it is encouraging to hear.

Answer (score 3):

I have been assured from Google that as long as you do the following, the warranty will be honored. Flash stock android back on the device (as described in the wiki at http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation), and re-lock the bootloader, by placing the device in fastboot mode, plugging into your computer, and running `fastboot oem lock`

There should be zero issues at this point, it will be as if you just bought a new device.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of completely removing touch from my N7. All you need is MultiROM installed on your device. Then select List ROMs, tap the one you want to remove and choose delete, as simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

Do I void the warranty? (In practice, not strictly legally. Can I bring the re-flashed device back to the store and pretend it's original?)

- **if you reset your device to a non-root mode, then you have your device within warranty**

Can I re-lock the bootloader?

- **according to me, when you install the stock ROM, you get your bootloader locked by default**

For more details on your questions, check following link :

http://www.jayceooi.com/2012/08/19/how-to-restore-stock-firmware-on-nexus-7-video/

Comment: This is a Windows-based method.  There is also instructions on how to do this under Ubuntu here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation (*Returning your Nexus 7 to Stock Android*)

Comment: Does this not contradict you: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasi *After restoring a factory image, it is recommended that you lock the bootloader, for security reasons.*